# Large unknown file - what is it?

Tags: windows-xp

This is on Windows XP. I just found out I have a directory called Admin on d:\ which is not visible with Explorer, only through command line. It lists its contents as:

```
 Directory of D:\Admin

11/25/2008  12:31 PM    <DIR>          DiskImages
10/30/2002  10:39 AM    <DIR>          Drivers
11/25/2008  01:00 PM    <DIR>          Images
03/05/2003  05:03 PM    <DIR>          RUN
11/25/2008  12:31 PM    <DIR>          Scripts
11/25/2008  12:31 PM    <DIR>          Tools_dos
11/25/2008  12:31 PM    <DIR>          Tools_w32
```

Now `D:\Admin\Images\25Nov08.sna` is a 3.2GB file, which I'd like to delete if it has no function. Any idea what it is? Most of the websites I looked at listed the `.sna` file extension as belonging to Drive SnapShot, but I've never used it.

Comment: Is this on a Dell or HP machine?  I would not be surprised if this is a recovery image for your machine.

Comment: Nope, it's a Compaq.

Comment: That entire folder looks like a recovery indeed. But it's weird they didn't create a separate partition for that, which they usually do.

Comment: You can always try renaming, rather than deleting, the folder and seeing if anything breaks. You might also take a look at the file in the `Scripts` folder and see if you can figure-out what they do.

Comment: Given its size, it could be a [Drive SnapShot disk image file](http://www.file-extensions.org/sna-file-extension-drive-snapshot-disk-image-file).

Comment: @Johnny [Compaq = HP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compaq#Acquisition_by_Hewlett-Packard)